# How to create Customer programmatically?

Tags: python, odoo

I am using Odoo 13 and trying to create customer programmatically with the help of ***res.partner*** but unable to create customer. Contact is creating but as a individual not as a customer. But in Odoo 12 there is a binary field ***customer*** which differentiate other contacts from customer but it is not present in Odoo 13.
Any suggestion or better idea and any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields were removed completely in V13. With module/app `account` two new fields will be created: `customer_rank` and `supplier_rank`, which will try to representate ranks for both situations. Odoo is setting the rank on creation to `1` on `customer_rank` when creating from customer menu or `supplier_rank` from supplier menu.

I suggest to just live with this big change or make a custom module which is getting back `customer` and `supplier` boolean fields.